# How do I add multiple images on TensorBoard callback for Keras

Tags: image, keras, tensorboard

I'm trying to add my validation set images to the TensorBoard callbacks of Keras.  The following code works and even gives me the slider for each batch step.
 
However, the batch step gets appended to the tag so it ends up showing each image as a separate tag (e.g. `predictions_1`, `predictions_2`, `predictions_3`).

**Is there some way I can keep the tag from getting appended?**

```py
class TensorBoardWithImages(K.callbacks.TensorBoard):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TensorBoardWithImages, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):

        logs = logs or {}

        val_data = self.validation_data

        a=np.random.randint(0, val_data[0].shape[0], 10)
        tf.summary.image(name="predictions", tensor=val_data[0][a],
                         max_outputs=3)

        summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

        self.writer.add_summary(summary_op.eval(session=self.sess), batch)

        super(TensorBoardWithImages, self).on_batch_end(batch, logs)
```